# Rails store session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

As I know, we can config how to store session in a Rails app.  I want to know if it's possible we store session in two modes at same time ? which means one part in browser and other part in cache like memcached ?

Comment: why not store everything in the same place?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just want to know if it's possible or not ?

Comment: Nope, not possible. Not in stock rails, anyway.

Comment: Its not possible out of the box but you can easily use the cookie store and store something in memcached with the session id as a key (or store an arbitrary memcached key in the cookie store). But it does require a bit more work and thought from your part. Note that this does not mean that it will automatically unpack into the `session` hash. You would need to do that manually.

Comment: @max thank you for your answer meaningful. Acturely if I should write code, I will keep my sessions in cache.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom sub-class of `ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore`,  implement the required methods and register it as your session store. I suggest that you look at the source code for some existing stores: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/595c798c1763d7d2ee6939c5cf196ac31aef33da/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb

If I understand correctly, your class would need to create an instance of `MemCacheStore` and `CookieStore` and delegate to them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your `thoughtful answer `, In fact, I don't want to spend time to the dev. I locate juste a simple config native in Rails. Finally Its not possible.